# Switch session behaviour based on the Flask route

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

Is it possible to switch Flask session backends on a per-route basis?

My site stores all sessions in Redis with `RedisSessionInterface`. Each time a new visitor comes a new session gets written to Redis, hence there's a problem when there're thousands of visitors (real visitors or not) come within a few hours I run out of RAM because Redis eats it.

I really need sessions for internal pages only (`/administration_area`) accessible by me, so I don't want a session to be started each time a visitor hits the index page (`/`).

Is it possible to start a new session only on specific routes or can we change the `RedisSessionInterface` implementation somehow so it won't open a new session on every route?

Comment: Copy edit; put the problem statement at the start, break up the question into paragraphs. I clarified your question so that it is clearer from the outset what you are asking. Interesting question, good luck!

Comment: If you haven't already, take note of [@app.before_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/dbcon/) and [request.path](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.path).

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks. In my defense, it was late, i was tired. Didn't ever think someone will notice the question :)

Comment: @Celeo I'm aware of these, but how does it help me?

Comment: @KennyPowers: your question went through the Trial queue, then into the new Help and Improve queue. We try to notice!